# Where to find official documents that introduce the four-corner input method?

Tags: history, input-methods, technology

## Table of contents

- The context
- Information about the input method
- The questions

## The context

I'm interested in learning how to use the [Four-Corner Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-Corner_Method). I've started making some graphics of the decomposition of some characters in my computer (please see image below). The font I use for the character is "Noto Serif CJK SC", this font didn't exist at the time of the creation of the input method.

[image]

As I was decomposing the characters I recalled that the font can influence the way a character is displayed (which assigned to a unique Unicode code). I thought that this was clearly influencing the way I was understanding the input method, so I wished I could see the font that the creator of the input method took into consideration when creating this input method. This way, I could understand the authentic input method.

For this reason, I'm looking for documents published by formal organizations or (if possible the creator himself) that introduce this input method so that I can see the font that was kept in mind when the input method was published. This was, I avoid using a font that display characters differently and that wasn't taken into consideration by the creator or editors of the input method.

## Information about the input method

In [the Wikipedia page of the Four-Corner method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-Corner_Method), it is mentioned that [王雲五 (Wang Yun-wu)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Yun-wu) created the input method in the 1920s while he was working for [The Commercial Press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Commercial_Press) and that the input method has gone through some changes. The Wikipedia page mentions 3 revisions of the input method in [the "Versions" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-Corner_Method#Versions).

## The questions

- Are there any documents available online authored by Wang Yun-wu that give a formal explanation to this input method?
- If not, are there any published by the Commercial Press?
- If not, are there any published by remarkable organizations?

Please don't redirect me to a tutorial X published by person Y on the Internet, unless it is published by a formal organization or a public institution or the person Y was influential in the creation or the revision of the input method.

Comment: I remember seeing it in some really old version of Xiandai Hanyu Cidian or Xinhua Zidian.

Comment: I found a PDF version of Xinhua Zidian that contains 四角号码检字表: https://math.wvu.edu/~hlai2/My_Dictionary_CHN.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down a book written by Wang Yun-wu himself in 1967 and published by the Taiwan Commercial Press called [四角号码检字法](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/%E5%9B%9B%E8%A7%92%E5%8F%B7%E7%A0%81%E6%A3%80%E5%AD%97%E6%B3%95/RA7PzbThUH0C?hl=en&gbpv=0) on Google Books, which even has a preview. Unfortunately, the preview, at least on my computer, is only 14 pages, but that should be enough.

Comment: Thanks! That document is a treasure for me as I'm interested in the history of the development of Chinese input methods. I've asked a similar question but related to 五笔输入法: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54193 , it hasn't been answered yet. People knowledgeable on this topic or interested on this might know the answer so I'm sharing it here.